# Combining different columns powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, duplicates

i need to combine csv-entries which is in this format:

```
ID, "Name", "Sex",  "Age"
1, "John", "m", "24"
2, "John", "m", "28"
2, "John", "m", "30"
3, "Melissa", "f", "24"
3, "Melissa", "f", "26"
```

to:

```
ID, "Name", "Sex", "Age", "Age" ,"Age"
1, "John", "m", "24", "28", "30"
3, "Melissa", "f", "24", "26"
```

What i got so far:

```
$csvData = Import-Csv 'test.csv'
$csvData | Group-Object "ID" | ForEach-Object {
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        "ID" = $_.Name
        "Sex" = $_.Group."Sex" -join '","'
        "Age" = $_.Group."Age" -join '","'
    }
} | Export-Csv 'test_output.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

which returns me this:

```
"ID","Name", "Sex", "Age"
"1", "John", "John", "John", "m", "m", "m", "24", "28", "30"
"2", "Melissa", "Melissa", , "f", "f", "24", "26"
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: Your desired output leaves you with an unusable csv file because column headers ('Age') are repeated. Also, how can someone with ID 2 ('John') or 3 ('Melissa') have **two** ages? ID's are to uniquely identify objects/people,artefacts..

Comment: Thats ture, the headers should be Age1, Age2, Age3. The age is just an example. This isnt the "real" data, just an explanation for my understanding.

Comment: Sure, I understand this is fake data, but.. in real life, there should not be duplicate ID's and if you group on Name, then why not consider Sex aswell? You can have names for men AND women alike.. such as 'Kim' for instance or "A boy named Sue"..

Comment: i do understand that. but your clarifications for "reallife" situation isnt helpful. Its more like "i want to learn how to do it"... let's call it a "self-directed" challenge...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right, then this is only meant to be an exercise in PowerShell foo and not in meaningful data manipulation.

Under that premise: One way you could create your desired output (and end up with a valid csv), is to add numbered properties for each "Age" value that you want to include in the consolidated objects.

```
$csvData = Import-Csv 'test.csv'
$csvData | Group-Object Name | ForEach-Object {

    $obj = [ordered]@{
        ID = $_.Group[0].ID
        Name = $_.Name 
        Sex = $_.Group[0].Sex
    }
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $_.Group.Count; $i++) {

        $obj["Age$($i+1)"] = $_.Group[$i].Age
    }
    [PsCustomObject]$obj
} | Export-Csv 'test_output.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```